# iOS keychain issue. SecKeyRef always is null as result of SecItemCopyMatching()

Tags: objective-c, ios, keychain

SecKeyRef is always null even though I'm not getting any errors from any of the statuses. I initially thought it was an arc issue but the casts look ok. Any help would be appreciated.

```
+ (SecKeyRef)addPublicKey:(NSString *)key withTag:(NSString *)tag
    {
        // This will be base64 encoded, decode it.
        NSData *d_key = [key dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        if (d_key == nil) return (FALSE);

        NSData *d_tag = [NSData dataWithBytes:[tag UTF8String] length:[tag length]];

        // Delete any old lingering key with the same tag
        NSMutableDictionary *publicKey = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [publicKey setObject:(__bridge id) kSecClassKey forKey:(__bridge id)kSecClass];
        [publicKey setObject:(__bridge id) kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrKeyType];
        [publicKey setObject:d_tag forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrApplicationTag];
        SecItemDelete((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)publicKey);

        CFTypeRef persistKey = nil;

        // Add persistent version of the key to system keychain
        [publicKey setObject:d_key forKey:(__bridge id)kSecValueData];
        [publicKey setObject:(__bridge id) kSecAttrKeyClassPublic forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrKeyClass];
        [publicKey setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:(__bridge id)kSecReturnPersistentRef];

        OSStatus secStatus = SecItemAdd((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)publicKey, &persistKey);

        NSLog(@"OSStatus = %ld", secStatus);  // Always returns no error = 0

        if (persistKey != nil) CFRelease(persistKey);

        if ((secStatus != noErr) && (secStatus != errSecDuplicateItem)) {
            return nil;
        }

        // Now fetch the SecKeyRef version of the key
        SecKeyRef keyRef;

        [publicKey removeObjectForKey:(__bridge id)kSecValueData];
        [publicKey removeObjectForKey:(__bridge id)kSecReturnPersistentRef];
        [publicKey setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:(__bridge id)kSecReturnRef];
        [publicKey setObject:(__bridge id)kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrKeyType];


        secStatus = SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)publicKey, (CFTypeRef *)&keyRef);

        NSLog(@"secStatus = %ld", secStatus); // Always returns no error = 0

        return keyRef; // Always null!
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was working on something similar and came across this post. I tried out your code and it worked fine for me so I think it is correct. I suspect that the key data is wrong. I tried feeding bad key data through this method and it gave me back a null reference like you stated. I am building a public key (ASN.1 DER) from a modulus and exponent using this-

https://github.com/meinside/iphonelib/blob/master/security/CryptoUtil.m#L67

Please note there are couple of pending pull requests.

I think perhaps you should try a .cer file or generate an rsa key with openssl and use the modulus and exponent with CryptoUtil.

Answer (score 0):

i realize this is an old question, but i had the same problems, so i'll add my findings here. maybe it'll help someone out.

first off, in your case, it doesn't look like you are decoding the RSA key. you have the comment to decode the base64 encoded key, but then you just convert it to an NSData object. you do have to base64 decode the RSA key.

second, make sure you strip the headers and any new lines out of the key string.

then base64 decode the string and convert it to NSData to use for the kSecValueData.

in my case, i was converting the key to NSData and then decoding it...not sure if that was an issue with the decoder or not, but I kept getting an empty secKeyRef. my decoder only worked when i decoded the key string and then converted to NSData.

that one piece of info was holding me back for a while.

Answer (score -1):

I too was facing the problem, and finally could resolve it by sending in the input data(key param) in the right format, which is in ASN.1 DER format. The below method was not yielding any key despite no errors and status code 0 just like @reedjsmith mentioned - when the data was sent in as any other format (plain base64 encoded data) or key data generated with anything other than PKCS#1 padding.

- (SecKeyRef)addPublicKey:(NSString *)key withTag:(NSString *)tag

Comment: This is a question, not an answer. If you can't comment, you won't be able to anytime soon if you post answers as questions.